# CardView background is black in preview

Tags: android-studio, cardview

When creating an empty CardView in Android, Android Studio shows me a CardView with a black background in the preview.
When I install the app on the device, the background of the cardview changes to the default one. 
Has it to do something with the styles.xml file?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to update the [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) to version `27.1.0`. Downgrading to the previous version (`27.0.2`) solves this little problem.

However, I'd use `27.1.0` and wait for a fix since, as you say, this problem only happens in preview.